# Color 'print' in Python

Tags: python, printing, colors

Been going thru this: [How do I print colored text to the terminal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/287871/how-do-i-print-colored-text-to-the-terminal). My issue is little different than those solutions (or I just can't find it). I need to print two variables in different colors in same print statement.

For example
print("{0} {1}".format(test1, test2))
Should print 'one' in RED and 'two' in BLUE.

Below works for single line. But how do I combine them.

```
os.system("")
class style():
  RED = '\033[31m'
  GREEN = '\033[32m'
  BLUE = '\033[34m'
  RESET = '\033[0m'

test1 = "ONE"
test2 = "TWO"

print(style.RED + "{0}".format(test1) + style.RESET)
print(style.GREEN + "{0}".format(test2) + style.RESET)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [f-strings](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings):

```
print(f"{style.RED}{test1} {style.BLUE}{test2}{style.RESET}")
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind, allow me to refactor your code to make it more *pythonic* and eventually more readable:

```py
class Style():
  RED = "\033[31m"
  GREEN = "\033[32m"
  BLUE = "\033[34m"
  RESET = "\033[0m"

print(f"{Style.RED}ONE{Style.RESET}")
print(f"{Style.GREEN}TWO{Style.RESET}")
```

You can combine the strings like this:

```py
red_text = f"{Style.RED}ONE{Style.RESET}"
green_text = f"{Style.GREEN}TWO{Style.RESET}"

print(f"{red_text} {green_text}")
```

[F-strings were introduced in Python 3.6](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/). If you're using an earlier version of Python, you can simply use string concatenation with a `+` between strings (instead of the less readable `format()` function):

```py
print(Style.RED + "ONE" + Style.RESET)

red_text = Style.RED + "ONE" + Style.RESET
```

Instead of coding everything from scratch, you could also check other Python packages. For example [Colorist](https://jakob-bagterp.github.io/colorist-for-python/) – a lightweight package that enables you to add style and colour to text messages in the terminal (in full disclosure, I'm the author of this package). This may simplify your code:

```py
from colorist import red, green

red("ONE")
green("TWO")
```

[image]

Another variation if you want to keep the f-strings. The output is the same:

```py
from colorist import Color

print(f"{Color.RED}ONE{Color.OFF}")
print(f"{Color.GREEN}TWO{Color.OFF}")
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the print statement's built in `end` parameter instead of `os`. This is how you would do it:

```
class style():    
    RED = '\033[31m'
    GREEN = '\033[32m'
    BLUE = '\033[34m'
    RESET = '\033[0m'

test1 = "ONE"
test2 = "TWO"

print(style.RED + "{0}".format(test1) + style.RESET, end='')
print(style.GREEN + "{0}".format(test2) + style.RESET, end='')
```

And no, I don't think you can combine them.

Another thing. Your class notation is not good. Normally, you should use the **init** function to initialize your variables.

In this case, a class is a bad idea to store those strings. I think you should define those as variables instead of in a class, like follows:

```
RED = '\033[31m'
GREEN = '\033[32m'
BLUE = '\033[34m'
RESET = '\033[0m'

test1 = "ONE"
test2 = "TWO"

print(RED + "{0}".format(test1) + RESET, end='')
print(GREEN + "{0}".format(test2) + RESET, end='')
```